# Create image-stream on image from private registry on OpenShift

Tags: docker, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I've set up an OpenShift Origin 1.1.3 cluster. Now I'm pulling images from a private registry. This registry is 'insecure'. It has self-signed certificates and credentials to authenticate. I'm able to perform a `docker login` and to pull the image manually on my node.

The problem is that only that node can access the image. So when I'm scaling my pod (based on that image), all replica's will run on that specific node. Other nodes are not able to pull or use the image.

So I want to create an image-stream for my image:

```
oc import-image --insecure=true ec2-xxx:5000/image

But:       message: you may not have access to the Docker image "ec2-xxx:5000/image"
      reason: Unauthorized
```

I read about creating a secret. I created it:

```
oc secrets new-dockercfg mysecret --docker-server=ec2-xxx:5000 --docker-username=*** --docker-password=*** --docker-email=any@mail.com
```

How do I have to add this secret to my image-stream? And is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cloudnoob his answer helped me a lot.
But the main problem was that I've created my secret in the wrong way.
I saw this after starting the OpenShift master with loglevel 5.

```
Unable to find a secret to match https://ec2-xxx:5000/v2/test/image/manifests/83
```

So I had to create my secret with https (it's called insecure with selfsigned certificates but it's using https):

```
oc secrets new-dockercfg mysecret --docker-server=https://ec2-xxx:5000 --docker-username=*** --docker-password=*** --docker-email=any@mail.com
```

After this step I had to perform the steps of cloudnoob. Adding the secrets to the service accounts. After that the import is a succes.

Answer (score 0):

[Openshift Origin Doc](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/image_pull_secrets.html)
To use a secret for pulling images for pods, you must add the secret to your service account. The name of the service account in this example should match the name of the service account the pod will use; default is the default service account:

$ oc secrets add serviceaccount/default secrets/ --for=pull

To use a secret for pushing and pulling build images, the secret must be mountable inside of a pod. You can do this by running:

$ oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but I still have the same issue. Is the name of my created secret important? I'm able to create the secret. To add it to the service account. But the error remains (when I create an is)

Comment: loglevel 5 gave me this: Unable to find a secret to match https://ec2-xxx:5000/v2/test/image/manifests/83 (ec2-xxx:5000/v2/test/image/manifests/83)
I0302 07:41:05.054381   37500 importer.go:430] unable to access tag "83" for repository